# Javascript+JSDoc: strict use only properties defined in constructor

Tags: javascript, dojo, webstorm, jsdoc

Is there any way to fire warning, if class property is used without implicit definition in constructor? Like this:

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare"],
    function (declare) {
        return declare("MyClass", [], {

            /**
             * @constructor
             */
            constructor: function () {
                /**
                 * @type {number}
                 * @private
                 */
                this.a = 1;
            },

            doSomething: function () {
                this.a = 2; //Ok
                this.b = 3; //Want warning here, if b is not defined in constructor
            }

        });
    });
```

I use JS+Dojo+JSDoc+Webstorm

Comment: there is no way to do this currently. Please vote for [WEB-9249](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-9249)